# How to safely use do.call() within dplyr pipe

Tags: r, dplyr, lapply, sapply, do.call

Let's say that I wish to create a function that will allow a user to extract the min/max of the x/y values of `sf` objects, like each US State. I can do something like this:

```r
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(spData)

bound <- function(obj, dim, type) {
    tmp_fn <- function(obj, dim, type) {
    obj %>%
      st_coordinates() %>%
      data.frame() %>%
      pull(dim) %>%
      do.call(what = type, args = list(.))
  }

  bound_var <- sapply(obj$geometry, tmp_fn, type = type, dim = dim)
  return(bound_var)
}

min_x <- bound(us_states, "X", "min")
```

This works as expected but results in warnings:

```
There were 49 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
> warnings()
1: In if (quote) args <- lapply(args, enquote) :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (quote) args <- lapply(args, enquote) :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
3: In if (quote) args <- lapply(args, enquote) :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
...
```

The issue is is `do.call`. The argument to `args` is a list of length 1 -- and I think it always would be but I'm not certain -- and that object is a vector from the previous chain of pipes. While it works, I'm wondering if there is a safer way that avoids having to hardcode the `type` input (e.g., "min" in my example) that I'm using in `do.call()`.

Comment: once you pull dim, you should just call the function ie `..pull(dim)%>%type()`. Also you could often use `invoke` instead of `do.call`

Comment: Maybe `{exec(type, !!!.)}`?

Comment: `invoke` is soft-deprecated, `exec` is the new favored-function within `rlang`.

Comment: @IanCampbell That worked, except without the `!!!`. Feel free to create an answer and I'll mark it correct.